# Windows 8.1 transparency?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, taskbar, transparency

So I have two computers. Both of which are running Windows 8.1 (Version 6.3 Build 9600). The only real differences in the systems are that one is Pro, and the other is.. I'm not sure. It simply says "Windows 8.1", so I'm assuming that's Windows 8's equivalent to Home Premium. Anyway, On the non-pro system, I have this really nice effect out of box where my task bar is semi-transparent, and I love it. It makes for a really clean feel when working on the computer. However, my Windows 8.1 Pro system does not have this.. it has a solid opaque task bar out of the box. What I'm curious about, is how to get the effect enabled on the 8.1 Pro system.. I've posted a few images related to the issue, and labeled them with the corresponding system. Any help with this issue would be amazing.

**How it looks on the working system ->**

[image]

**How it looks on the non-working system ->**

[image]

(Check Edit History)

**Images**

**Not working system**
[image: CMD System Informatin]
[image: System Information]

**Working System**
[image: CMD System Information]
[image: System Information]

*Note: I'm new to superuser. I've been using stackoverflow for a very long time, and didn't know if this was the right place to post this question or not. If not, please simply let me know. Thanks a ton!*

Comment: Are you using Classic Shell on Pro system?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I made the edit within the 5 minute grace period and completely forgot that edits made within 5 mins of the original post won't be saved.

Comment: @Haplo I don't think so.. Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: What graphics card\chip is in the nonfunctional system?

Comment: @Mokubai The non-functional system is using a GeForce GTX 660 Ti Boost. The functional system is using a AMD RAdeon HD 7310

Comment: Nvidia drivers all installed and up to date? If you right click on the desktop and go to "personalise" does changing the theme help at all?

Comment: From my experience, you can't make taskbar opaque without 3rd party software or changing the theme. So, try using default themes or see if an application is installed that can affect this situation.

Comment: SO, It turns out it was something with NVidea. I went into the NVidea control panel, and did a fresh install on it. It resolved the issue. I have no idea what was doing it, But the solution was to do a fresh install on the nvidea software. Thanks a ton for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy comment chain above, I found that doing a fresh install of my NVidea drivers fixed this. Even though they were already up to date, it fixed it. Hope this helps someone in the future.